# get a single value of array items in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in my php code, but I don't know how to get the value of it.

my array :

```
$year =  array(
    'data' => to_html(strtr(to_lang('main/date_format_other_years'), array(
    '^day' => '',
    '^month' => '',
    '^year' => date('Y', $timestamp),
 ))),
);
```

I have a variable named `$stringyear`, how can I set it to 'year' value of this array?

Comment: what do to_html and to_lang functions do?

Comment: these are other external functions that get time of the post created to html and get language of selected item.

Comment: sure, that's cool, but could you post the code for them too - so that we can run this code and var_dump it.

Comment: `to_html(strtr(to_lang('main/date_format_other_years')` return me the value of language if time is not for this year(2010). and `tohtml` convert the special time format to an array.

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($year)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to access it as follows:

```
$stringyear = $year[1]['^year'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `$stringyear = $year['data']['^year'];`

Comment: its return 222! but array return me 2012!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `to_html` function returns, If it returns a string (for displaying in html), then you can not get it (You can but you need to parse the string again).

Since you have the `$timestamp`, why not just do with:

```
$stringyear = date('Y', $timestamp);
```